# Why does my app require me to log in as a user after I log in as an admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason, I am redirected to a user sign-up page after I log-in as an admin. And if I log-in as a regular user, I get the privileges the admin has such as the ability to create and delete posts.

route.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
  devise_for :admins, path: 'admins'
  root 'home#index'
  get '/' => "courses#index", as: :user_root
    resources :courses, :lessons
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  private
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    courses_path
  end

  def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading"><h2><%= @lesson.title %></h2></div>
  <div class="panel-body"><%= @lesson.content %></div>
</div>

</p>

<% if admin_signed_in? %>
<%= link_to "delete lesson", lesson_path(@lesson), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<%= link_to "edit lesson", edit_lesson_path %>
<% end %>
<br>
<br>
<%= link_to "<<back to lesson", course_path(@lesson.course_id)%>
```

Any other files which could be causing this issue?

Comment: Seems like an `Admin` and a `User` are different models in your application. Therefore `authenticate_user` expects a user to be signed in not an admin. Did you consider modeling admins to just being normal users, but with an `admin=true` flag?

Comment: @spickermann I chose the way using devise to create multiple models instead of creating a User model and having an admin attribute to it. So I'm assuming you are saying that the before_action :authenticate_user! part of the code should be changed to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`authenticate_user` checks if a `User` is logged in or redirects to the `sign_in_path` otherwise. In a similar way, `authenticate_admin` would check for an `Admin`.

Because your application is designed to allow different models to sign in you cannot use these `devise` methods. Instead, you will need to write your own method that checks both before redirecting.

Something like the following might work for you:

```
before_action :authenticate_admin_or_user

private

def authenticate_admin_or_user
  redirect_to(sign_in_path_path) unless admin_signed_in? || user_signed_in?
end
```